# error message on oncomplete in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, oncomplete

I would Like to add Error message on visualfocepage if save button logic has error. this part is working ,but i need to show popup if there are no error messages.how to add condition to show popup only if there are no error messages and if error messages found then dont show popup(display only error messages)
SUDO:

```
if(errors==NULL){
showpopup
}else{
show error messages &ignore popup
}


<apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="showmsg" oncomplete="window.open('/apex/popuppage','_blank','height=400,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)" />`
```

controller

```
if(notAllow){
        Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'record already has an active status'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing

oncomplete of save button call a javascript function and check if notAllow false then open pop up

```
<apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" 
    rerender="showmsg,scriptPanel" oncomplete="openPage();" />

<apex:outputpanel id="scriptPanel"> 
<script>
function openPage()
{
  if('{!notAllow}' == 'false')
  {
    window.open('/apex/popuppage','_blank','height=400,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1);
  }
}
</script>
<apex:outputpanel>
```

Comment: Ratan,thanks for the reply.  {!notAllow} is not available in VF. its in controller, is there  a way to check if error messages are empty

Comment: @patha make that variable get set, so this variable will be available in vf page.

Comment: @patha cool....

Answer (score 2):

This code will work for you.

Use notAllow attribute in the javascript function at `oncomplete` function itself.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page controller="myController2">
<apex:pageMessages id="showmsg"></apex:pageMessages>
<apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" rerender="showmsg" 
    oncomplete="javacript: if({!notAllow==false})window.open('/apex/popuppage','_blank','height=400,location=no,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=1', 1)" />`
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public boolean notAllow {get;set;}
        public PageReference save()
        {
            notAllow = false; //change it to true to show error message
            if(notAllow){
                Apexpages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'record already has an active status'));
            } 
            return null;
        }
```